# Crontab Job Raspberry Python Script Influxdb

Tags: python, syntax, cron, raspberry-pi, precision

This is my  `/etc/crontab` file:

```
 1-59/1 * * * *  root    python3 /home/pi/HP_AD_HAT1/python/maininfluxdb.py
```

I would like to get my sensor data exactly every full minute in every hour over the day.

Why is my following code not working. If I run the script manually everything is fine. I also checked twice location and file name.

Thanks for help

I also tried crontab -e instructions..

[crontab -e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYhNg.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

In your normal shell/Terminal, run:

```
type python3
```

then you'll get the full path to your Python3 interpreter. Use that in your `cron` job.

Note also that `crond` doesn't go through the full login and shell setup sequence as when you log in, so if your script relies on paths and aliases, they need to be set up equivalently in `cron`.

**Original Answer**

You don't specify `cron` jobs by creating a file in `/etc`.

Instead, you define your preferred editor, then run the `crontab` command like this:

```
export EDITOR=vi
crontab -e
```

If you think about it, it has to be this way because each user gets their own `crontab` so it won't be a single file in `/etc`.

---

You can get a list of your `cron` jobs with:

```
crontab -l
```

Comment: I also tried that...please look edited screenshot

Comment: Ok. What's the problem exactly? Does it run at all? Or crash? Or give an error message? Or run at the wrong time?

Comment: the script does not run through crontab -.-

Comment: syntax seems right, the script works, the file location is also right

Comment: when i run in terminal: python /home/pi/HP_AD_HAT1/python/maininfluxdb.py everything works, so why the heck isnt it working with cron.. I dont get it

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please look again.

Comment: i tried nearly everything.. its so frustrating. i dont get it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0XruTkZHxM

Comment: https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1306432#p1306432

Comment: Rather than complain that it doesn't work, you need to be more thorough and methodical about your approach. Stop using `sudo` because that is a different user with a different environment. Run something simple without `python` every minute, just using `bash`. Then run some simple Python. Build one step at a time. Be methodical. Update your question so it accurately reflects what you are doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040075/cron-a-python3-script

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, it has to do with the comportment of crontab, when it is executing a script, it is doing so with sudo "user". Therefore pythons libraries must also be installed with "sudo" user : sudo pip3 install  and not simply pip3 install  as I used to.